# Any python library to convert PDF- English to PDF-French

Tags: python, pdf, google-translate, translate

I am really confused with the existing libraries inside python for language translation. Is there any python library which can be used to convert the pdf in the English version to pdf in French.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about it but I know py-translate this might help you for more visit [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-translate/).

Everything is there from installation to doc..

**EDIT:**

Visit: https://awesome-python.com/ you might find something useful..

Comment: I have already checked it @SagarVipara. But I was looking for entire document conversion.

Comment: So you have French version of pdf and you want to convert it into the English version of that to the pdf am I right ?

Comment: English document to French document.

Comment: Is it doc or pdf ?

Comment: I need to convert pdf English version to pdf French version

Comment: I don't know if there is any library that help you to do it easily.
What you can do is:
1) Extract the text.
2) Translate It.
3) Create PDF.

Don't forget to preserve the layout while translating. This is how it internally works.